# How to use class type array in different forms in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am beginner to c#. I am stuck on this assignment. I am trying to store values in class type global array but array is not saving this. I have tried a lot but failed.

Here is the code:

```
public class GlobalVariable
{

    public static Employeeclass[] staff = new Employeeclass[10];
    public static int total=0;
}

public class Employeeclass
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public double salary;   
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myform = new Form2();
        myform.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myForm = new Form3();
        myForm.Show();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double totalsalary = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVariable.total; i++)
        {
            totalsalary+=GlobalVariable.staff[i].salary;
        }
        string a = GlobalVariable.total.ToString();
        string b = totalsalary.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("total employee = " + a +"\ntotal salary = " + b);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form 
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2 == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please enter employee name");
        }
        else
        {
            GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].name = textBox2.Text;
            GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].salary = 0.0;
            GlobalVariable.total++;  
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = (GlobalVariable.total + 1).ToString();
    }
}

public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    //string temp;
    //double a;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

         for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVariable.total; i++)
         {
             comboBox1.Items.Insert(i,GlobalVariable.name[i]);
             // comboBox1.Items.Add(GlobalVariable.name[i]);
         }
         if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
         {
             textBox1.Enabled = true;
         }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myform = new Form2();
        myform.Show();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At no point do you declare the `staff` elements, you need to initialize all elements

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't initialize the employees. You have to create a new instance of the employee first (unlike with structs, where the default is already a fully working "instance"):

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2 == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please enter employee name");
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a new instance in the array
        GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total] = new Employeeclass();

        GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].id = 
          Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].name = textBox2.Text;
        GlobalVariable.staff[GlobalVariable.total].salary = 0.0;
        GlobalVariable.total++;  
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

However, I have to point out this is a very unhappy design. Global variables? Fixed-length arrays for variable-length data? Non-existent encapsulation?

For example, a better way might be to create the dialogs as, well, dialogs:

```
private NewEmployeeForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public static EmployeeClass ShowDialog()
{
  var frm = new NewEmployeeForm();

  while (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(frm.tbxName.Text))
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Please, enter the employee name.");
    }
    else
    {
      var emp = new EmployeeClass();
      emp.Id = int.Parse(frm.tbxId.Text);
      emp.Name = frm.tbxName.Text);
      return emp;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Forget coding like it's 1980. It's really necessary to separate your code into more or less isolated parts. Read up a bit on object oriented programming, especially encapsulation. Use meaningful names for your variables and controls, even in your learning projects! You really need the habit, it's non-negotiable.

Also, try to look for a way that solves your problem first. For example, there's a `List` class in .NET, that handles a self-expanding list of data. So you can use something like this:

```
List<EmployeeClass> employees = new List<EmployeeClass>();
employees.Add(emp1);
employees.Add(emp2);
employees.Add(emp3);

MessageBox.Show("I've got " + employees.Count + " employees!");
```

Don't forget error handling. I know you're just making a learning project, but again, you want the right habits. Parsing a string to an integer? Check that it's actually an integer first. Handle the possible exception. Use data validation. If I enter `hi` in your textBox1, your application is going to crash or show an "break / continue / abort" dialogue. That's not good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each of the "EmployeeClass" Objects in your array.
By default, when the array is created it has 10 slots filled with "null"

I recommend adding a static constructor:

```
public static class GlobalVariable
{
    public static Employeeclass[] staff;
    public static int total=0;

    static GlobalVariable()
    {
        staff = new Employeeclass[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < staff.Length; i++)
            staff[i] = new EmployeeClass();
    }
}
```

The static constructor is called when you first reference anything in the GlobalVariable class. Also the class should be declared "static" because all of its members are static. The compiler can make more efficient code in this way.

Cheers and good luck learning C#

Comment: "The compiler can make more efficient code in this way." More importantly, it acts as a safeguard for you - you will not create non-static stuff or new instances by mistake. It's really useful to make sure the compiler saves you from as many mistakes as possible - that's when they're very easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVariable.total; i++)
```

`GlobalVariable.total` is 0, so this loop will never be run through. Either set `total` to 10, or change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GlobalVariable.staff.Count; i++)
```

Also, there's no actual elements in the staff array, so it wouldn't work anyway.